# Why am I getting a 'Segmentation Fault' error in my code?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, palindrome

I have this code to check for a palindrome in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char* test="racecar";
    Palindrome(test, 7);
}

int Palindrome(char mystr[], int len){
    if(len<2)
        printf("Palindrome");
    else if (mystr[0]==mystr[len-1]){
        char* newstr;
        int i=0;
        int j=1;
        while(j<len-1){
            newstr[i]=mystr[j];
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        printf("%s", newstr);
        return Palindrome(newstr, len-2);
    }
    else
        printf("Not palindrome");
}
```

But I am getting this error: **Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

Why is this?

Comment: Because `newstr` is unallocated and points nowhere.

Comment: Trying to 1) index into an, and 2) copy a value into an unallocated pointer.  `newstr[i]=mystr[j]`. Aside, there is no need for recursion when searching for a palindrome; it really only complicates matters.

Comment: And you really don't need it. You can pass the original string around instead along with the start and end index.

Comment: `return Palindrome(mystr+1, len-2);`

Comment: @EugeneSh. thanks. Is there a way to create an empty char pointer, or an empty string? And then be able to copy values into it.

Comment: @S3DEV this is a HW question assigned, we were given the function declaration and had to complete it..

Comment: `char newstr[len] = {0};` should solve it. The initialization with zeros is essential as you don't explicitly terminate the string. But again, you don't need it.

Comment: Also to note that not returning from a function that has non-void return type is undefined behavior, your have 2 paths that return nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `char *newstr` is uninitialized which cause your segfault when you deference it.
2. return an int when you declare the function as such.
3. (advise) It's a good idea to terminate lines with a `\n`.

The way you structured your code I thought you were going for a recursive algorithm:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int Palindrome(char mystr[], size_t len) {
    if(len < 2) {
        printf("Palindrome\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if(mystr[0] != mystr[len-1])
        printf("Not palindrome\n");
        return 0;
    }
    return Palindrome(mystr + 1, len - 2);
}

int main(void) {
    char *test = "racecar";
    Palindrome(test, strlen(test));
}
```

and the corresponding output is:

```
Palindrome
```

Here is how I would write the iterative version:

```
int Palindrome(char mystr[], int len){
    for(; len > 1; mystr++, len -= 2) {
        if(*mystr != mystr[len - 1]) {
            printf("Not palindrome\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("Palindrome\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Allan. What does returning Palindrome(mystr + 1) do? Does it send the original String minus the first character?

Comment: Try and let me know.